# RAND() based on specific criteria

Tags: mysql

Basically I'm trying to create some kind of "algorithm" for selecting rows from a table.

Just imagine you've got a swimming pool full of **650** people, you want to run a machine that'll scoop down and grab **40** of them, bare in mind out of these **40** people, theirs 2 people in the pool that can only be grabbed very very rarely.

So now to put this is code terms:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    people
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT
    40
```

I then want to add some kind of "algorithm" to such query which does something like this but in mySQL

```
$rand = rand(4,100);
if($rand == 26) {
    //the option is now open to potentially scoop those rare people which have the ID of `15256` and `884`
}
```

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do.  What does "very very rarely" mean, for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in simple terms, I have 2 specific rows in my table that I don't want RAND() to grab very often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: using `ORDER BY RAND()` is bad idea in general, because it will produce huge performance impact. That is well-known fact, since `RAND()` will be evaluated on the fly and so leaving no way to use index on those values.

However, from theoretical point, you can define some borders and check if randomly generated value is there. That will lead you to something like:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  (SELECT
    pool.id AS id,
    name,
    IF(rare_ids.id IS NULL, 1, 1/@probability_divisor) AS probability,
    RAND() AS random
  FROM
    pool
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 3 AS id
      UNION ALL
     SELECT 7 AS id) AS rare_ids
    ON
      pool.id = rare_ids.id
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @probability_divisor:=10) AS init
  ) AS struct
WHERE
  random<probability
ORDER BY
  random
LIMIT 3
```

(check the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed3175/4))

Explanation on that - is that you're defining some probability divisor and later check if randomly generated value is inside interval `[0 .. 1/divisor]` - this, of course, relies on fact that `RAND()` is generating values from `[0 .. 1]`

In sample, `3` and `7` are chosen to be "rare people ids" and those people will appear in result set with 1/10 of normal probability. Also, I am selecting 3 rows with `LIMIT`, which you, most probably, will want to change.

Also, `LEFT JOIN` was made only to specify one definition place for ids and other used things. It can be replaced with `IN`, like:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  (SELECT
    id,
    name,
    IF(id IN (3, 7), 1/@probability_divisor, 1) AS probability,
    RAND() AS random
  FROM
    pool
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @probability_divisor:=10) AS init
  ) AS struct
WHERE
  random<probability
ORDER BY
  random
LIMIT 3
```

(with the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed3175/7))

Please, note, that for big data sets this will work extremely slow, but for sane amount of rows it's still applicable.